# How do I embed an adobe flash file or html inside of a java applet

Tags: java, swing, flash, applet, japplet

I want to run a flash game or html5 game inside of a java applet.
How would I do such a thing?

Comment: An applet is embedded in a web page, so why not just dispense with the applet and embed the HTML 5 in the page directly (in an iframe if necessary)?

Comment: In my case, my applet is downloaded locally and is run directly by my clients. What you said wouldn't be an option unfortunately.

Comment: *"my applet is downloaded locally and is run directly by my clients"* Then it shouldn't be an applet at all, but a (Swing `JFrame` of Java-FX based) desktop application that is installed using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).